# nodejs jade issue

Tags: node.js, pug

I my jade view I give the array 'arr':

server.js

```
app('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index', {
      arr: [1,2,3]
   });
});
```

I my index view I need to make something like this:

index.jade:

```
- if (arr && arr.length) {
     for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        div(class='div-'+arr[i]) 
- }
```

Eventually I want to get the following html code:

```
 <div class='div-1'>
 <div class='div-2'>
 <div class='div-3'>
```

But it does work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [readme (on github)](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/Readme.md) contains some examples under Syntax.

This example should do what you want:

```
- for (var key in obj)
  p= obj[key]
```

or in your case

```
- for var key in arr
  div(class='div-'+key)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get .'div-'+key .'div-'+key in HTML page

Comment: Hrmm there's probably a shorter way to write it, but you can write it out as div(class='div-'+key) then.